# Scale all ImageViews in LinearLayout to suit LinearLayout Width

Tags: android, imageview, width, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal linear layout that contains 5 image views. Each image view is a different width but all are the same height. 
In landscape orientation it looks fine (Image 1 below), however I when resize the linear layout to portrait the last image cannot fit and the second last is scaled to fit (Image 2 below).
What I want is all images to scale to fit the linear layout (Image 3 below).

Is this possible?

Perhaps there is a way of creating a fixed aspect ratio LinearLayout? That way the images would adjust to the height of the LinearLayout which would adjust to maintain aspect with the width of the LinearLayout which would adjust to fit the screen.

[image: Example Images]

Layout would be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image_01">
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image_02">
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image_03">
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image_04">
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image_05">
</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using android:layout_weight="1" for each image does not work. I get:

[image: Example Images]

Comment: Could you post your layout file?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
<LinearLayout android:weightSum="5" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the size static as per you reqiurement

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image_01" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image_02" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image_03" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image_04" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image_05" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Using something like 100dp width & height for all gives the same thing where all have equal width. If I give the actual px of each image in its width and height I get a strange result where the smallest width image is dropped to allow the others to part fit.